# C-string returns int/double/long value for the string

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm a beginner at C++ and my text book tell us some C-string Function:

```
int atoi(char s[]) // return int value for the string
double atof(char s[]) // return double value for the string
long atol(char s[]) // return long value for the string
```

What does these functions do?
Thank you

Comment: When I'm not on a linux machine, I end up typing "man atoi" on google to get the manual for a function. It works pretty well. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: cppreference has some good descriptions too

Answer (score 2):

`int atoi(const char s[])` accepts a null-terminated string and converts it into an `int`.

For example, if `"1234"` is passed into the function, it will return `1234` as an `int`.

If the string contains a decimal place, the number will be truncated, eg `"104.21"` will be returned as `104`.

Same for `long atol(char s[])`, using a `long` instead of an `int`.

For `double atof(char s[])`, the string is interpreted as a floating point number instead of an integral number, and is returned as a `double`.